# perl parsing configuration braces style

Tags: perl, csv

I wonder if perl can do parsing for braces configuration of junos and convert to csv.

```
interfaces {
  apply-groups policer-arp;
    ge-1/0/0 {
        description "*** Description ***";
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.100.200.1/24 {
                    arp 10.100.200.2 mac 00:16:d4:e7:9b:de;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-1/0/2 {
        description " Description ";
        vlan-tagging;
        unit 101 {
            description "NODEB_CLUSTER#101";
            vlan-id 101;
            family inet {
                address 10.187.132.3/27 {
                    vrrp-group 1 {
                        virtual-address 10.187.132.1;
                        priority 190;
                        accept-data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        unit 102 {
            description "Description";
            vlan-id 102;
            family inet {
                address 10.187.132.35/27 {
                    vrrp-group 2 {
                        virtual-address 10.187.132.33;
                        priority 200;
                        accept-data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        unit 103 {
            description "NODEB_CLUSTER#103";
            vlan-id 103;
            family inet {
                address 10.187.132.67/27 {
                    vrrp-group 3 {
                        virtual-address 10.187.132.65;
                        priority 190;
                        accept-data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        unit 104 {
            description "NODEB_CLUSTER#104";
            vlan-id 104;
            family inet {
                address 10.187.132.99/27 {
                    vrrp-group 4 {
                        virtual-address 10.187.132.97;
                        priority 200;
                        accept-data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
Interface, IP Address, VLAN, Virtual-Address, Vrrp-group, Vrrp Priority
ge-1/0/0,10.100.200.1/24, , , , ,               
ge-1/0/2, , , , , ,
ge-1/0/2.101,10.187.132.3/27,101,10.187.132.1,1,190
ge-1/0/2,102,10.187.132.35/27,102,10.187.132.33,2,200
ge-1/0/2,103,10.187.132.67/27,103,10.187.132.65,3,190
ge-1/0/2,104,10.187.132.99/27,104,10.187.132.97,4,200
```

So in brief, we convert junos configuration to csv, for interface configuration we counts interface ge-1/0/2, than ge-1/0/2.101 as it's interface for vlan 101, ge-1/0/2.102 for vlan 102, so on. 
Does perl can parse it or is there any quicker ways to convert it?

Comment: Perl (or any other programming language) can do that. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried read the input first, and then grep with if ($_ =~ //). But, it's hard to get the value when there's a duplicate value inside the config. I wonders if there's quicker ways?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be very difficult if you know grammar for this configuration. With combination of regexps (using **g** and **c** modifiers and **\G** assertion) and pos() function. Good example is [JSON::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON%3a%3aTiny).

I added parser example for this format (however don't know is it correct, because topic starter can't provide any specification): https://gist.github.com/olegwtf/7941326

Comment: I'm still confuse using JSON for tree-like, could you give some example for this case?

Comment: Has this config format grammar specification like JSON has https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627?

Comment: It seems not. Just like a tree without an object, only value/parameter.

Comment: This parser triggers events while parsing, like XML::SAX. So you should define your callbacks for what you want to do. I added some to show how it works. So, you can modify it for your needs.